# SunFrog Shirts API Sign In Returns Number or Key is Invalid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, restful-authentication

I am using SunFrog Shirts API and am making a `POST` request to the following url.

```
API:: https://api.sunfrogshirts.com/v1/Signup/addSignup.json
```

My params are below:

```
iAgree = 1
name = "Required"
email = "Required valid email"
password = "Required"
company = "Required"
address = "Required"
city = "Required"
state = "Required"
zipcode = "Required"
country = "Required". If USA, spell out entire country name, e.g. "United States".
```

When the request is complete, I receive the following failure response.

```
[
    {
        "ResponseAck": "Failure",
        "Message": "API Authentication Failure",
        "MessageDeveloper": "API Authentication Failure. Number or key is invalid."
    }
]
```

What am I missing and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST -d "{iAgree: 1, name: 'test', email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 1234567879, company: 'test', address: 'test', city: 'test', state: 'test', zipcode: 12345, country: 'test'}" -u username:password https://api.sunfrogshirts.com/v1/Signup/addSignup.json -H "ApiNumber:ApiKey"
```

Output::

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Please let me know about this error.